# linkShare integration in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to integrate linkShare affiliated link into the my iPhone application.

I have already created the links for the applications which I want to sell from within my application using my linkShare account.

But the only problem is how would I get the logo, name and description of those applications. Is there any kind of iTunes or other API available?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Apple provides various RSS feeds for searching the App Store. Also, see [this document (PDF)](http://www.apple.com/itunesaffiliates/API/AffiliatesSearch2.1.pdf) which seems to directly address your question.

Comment: Hi 

Thanks for replying. 

Actually I have gone through RSS feeds. But it gives specific results only.. Lets say for example top10 free apps, top10 paid apps..

But in my case I need these data (logo, name and description) for particular selected applications of my choice.

Thanks,